# using exec with a variable to start a php script

Tags: php, exec

When i visit my page, i want that page to start a housekeeping php script. The housekeeping script needs a varable to run.

```
/var/www/housekeeping.php?id=abc123
```

I dont want anything in return, just to start the houskeeping php script.

The next line does not work....

```
exec( 'php /var/www/housekeeping.php' , $myVariable | /dev/null &' );
```

I have also tried:
 require_once "xx
 include ("xx

Any tips to a novise that is learning the basic to code?

Comment: Perhaps use the full path to php? `/usr/bin/php` However, since you've placed the php script in the web root, why not simply load it through the webserver? `file_get_contents('http://domain/housekeeping.php?id='.$myVariable);`

Comment: Great idea, but its https: and behind htaccess so then i have to provide user:pass somehow.

Comment: This sounds like a job that should be called from cron on a regular basis (or scheduler if running on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$argv` for that call the following line:

`exec( 'php /var/www/housekeeping.php ' . $myVariable . ' | /dev/null &' );`

and change your housekeeping script into `$id = $argv[1]` (which is your variable) where `$argv[0]` is always the script name in this case `/var/www/housekeeping.php`.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Comment: Good idea, but i cant change id

Comment: @Bergum, you don't have access to the housekeeping.php script?